# Synchronizing Arrays in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, matrix, synchronization, monitor

So i'm going to be having a Matrix of size x * y. It's going to be made of objects of a specific class.

Now my conditions are that I need to be ensure that no other thread will be able to access two of the Array Locations at once. Because the thread using the Matrix will be moving from the first location to the second location and must have a lock on Both locations until the task finishes.

I would be expecting to have around 1..10 threads having access to the Matrix but it could be more.
Because so many threads will be required I will be having a ThreadPool and an executor.

I was hoping something like this would be possible. I was using the objects inside the matrices as locks themselves.

```
synchronized (matrix[x][y] && matrix[x][y+1]) //Where y+1 is just an example, it could be x+1, x-1.. etc.
{
    //In here I would be doing my modifications to the locations in the matrix I have locked.
}
```

I don't want to be locking whole rows or columns as that's not efficient for what I am attempting.

Would love some discussion about this as these ideas are bouncing around in my head.

Cheers.

Comment: You will probably want a two-dimensional array of ```AtomicInteger```s, some manipulation of ```AtomicReferenceArray``` or (most likely) some sort of hybrid with use of actual locks that operate on multiple indexes (like a ```ReadWriteReentrantLock``` perhaps?) . Synchronized blocks works on objects, not variables, so your example definitely will not do what you want it to do.

Comment: I don't think `AtomicInteger` will solve the problem, because you want the lock to span a pair of entries, not just one.  You may have to implement your own locking.

Comment: The array is made up of objects not variables.

Comment: No, an array is made up of references, not objects.

Comment: @Helium - this is still a problem. Consider that ```synchronized(matrix[x][y])``` may change inside the synchronized block, thus the next thread to hit that synchronized block could synchronize _on a completely different object_, thus not synchronizing at all.

Comment: The objects will never be changing, just the field inside it. Does it matter?

Comment: It... might work, but you'll want to be really sure that this never changes after initialization. Even then I'm not 100%. Furthermore I believe you'll have to do ```synchronized(matrix[x][y]) { synchronized(matrix[x][y+1]) {``` which could lead to deadlock situations. (If some other thread had [x][y+1] and needed [x][y] as the second lock, for instance)

Comment: If you have so much access to the matrix that using one big lock is going to be a problem, you have so much access that having to acquire and release two locks for each access is going to be a much bigger problem. There is probably a great solution to your problem, but we'd have to know a lot more about your problem to recommend one.

Answer (score 0):

An approach might be to have a separate "lock matrix" of the same size initialized to `0` or `false`.

The thread would request access to two positions of that matrix before working on the real matrix of objects. When granted access, the "lock matrix" sets the two entries to `1` or `true` and denies access to other threads requesting the same entries.